# Android JSOUP получение ссылки

Tags: android, jsoup

Только начинаю разбираться с библиотекой Jsoup, получилось взять заголовок сайта,

```
        Document doc = null
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://harrix.org").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {                
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         if (doc!=null)
            title = doc.title();
         else
            title = "Ошибка";
```

далее мне нужно взять ссылку, в коде страницы она имеет такой вид:

```
        <a class="online__link" href="/search">
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как взять ссылку такого типа? При этом на сайте эта ссылка отображается в виде строи/числа с количеством человек в он-лайне, то есть в Java хочу получить именно значение ссылки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить данный код

```
Element link = doc.select("a.online__link").first();
String text = link.text(); // отображаемый текст
```

Comment: Я в строке **String text = link.text(); // отображаемый текст** получаю **java.lang.NullPointerException**

Comment: @Digetix На странице скорее всего отсутствует нужный код. Можно ссылку на нее?

Comment: Страницы ещё нет в сети, только тестируется, но одновременно и делается клиент для сайта. А как он может отсутствовать есть я взял часть из кода? **<a class="online__link" href="/search">**

Comment: @Digetix стоит проверить какая страница загружается в doc

Answer (score 0):

У библиотеки Jsoup, есть замечательная страничка, где можно попробовать эту библиотеку в действии http://try.jsoup.org/

Попробуйте использовать css селектор `.online__link`.

На указанном в примере сайте, необходимый вам код не был обнаружен.

Пример:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element element = document.select(".online__link").first();
System.out.println("Текст ссылки: "+element.ownText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Кратко о Jsoup:
.text() - берет текст елемента
.html() - html
.attr("") - позволяет взять нужный параметр в классе, в вашем случае

```
Element link = doc.select("a.online__link").first();
```

String src = link.attr("href");